# Java how to listen for traffic on port without interfering

Tags: java, port

In Java how can I listen to see if there is any traffic on a port without interfering?

I have a java application that communicates via UDP with some hardware. However, there exists a legacy product that can remotely communicate with the hardware using port forwarding on 23982.

The two systems cannot communicate with the hardware at the same time so I need to **listen** on port 23982. If there is any traffic on the port (i.e. the legacy software is actively connecting to the hardware) I need to give the legacy system priority.

Hence I need to **listen** but not interfere with the traffic being forwarded from port 23982

Comment: What do you mean - do you want your java application to "record" all the traffic that goes through that port (without itself driving any communication?=

Comment: No, I literally need a boolean value telling me if anything if happening on the port. However, the act of 'listening' cannot interfere in any way with the traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int port = 23982;
java.net.ServerSocket serverSocket = new java.net.ServerSocket(port);
java.net.Socket client = serverSocket.accept(); 
// blocks until there is a connection-request. So you can
// now handle your notification, because if the program reaches this part of code, 
// a client has connected, e.g.:

boolean connected = true;
```

Comment: The docs for `ServerSocket.accept()` state **Listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it**. So lets say I run the above code, When there is no traffic all is well and the code blocks until there is a request. But what happens to the first packet arriving on port 23982? Surely it is consumed by the `java.net.Socket`? If so this constitutes interfering.

Comment: I'm marking this as the best answer but for anybody looking to use this in the future it does not meet the original questions requirements as the Socket consumes packets until its closed, hence it interferes with the traffic. However, for our needs loosing a couple of UDP packets was acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use [`ServerSocket`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just by opening port you are interfering with the traffic, the behavior would change from "unable to connect" which comes immediately to "server not responding" after some timeout.

Comment: My understanding was that if I opened a port I would interfere with the traffic.